# "in a similar way as" or "in a similar way to"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Consider the two statements:

> A is constructed in a similar way as B

and

> A is constructed in a similar way to B

Which one is correct, or can they both be?

By the way, I originally thought of the sentence is a weakened form the following:

> A is constructed in the same way as B

This might subconsciously lead me to prefer the former construction, although if I would expand the sentences above into imagined longer versions, I might have to choose between

> A is constructed in a similar way as the way in which B is constructed

and

> A is constructed in a way that is similar to the way in which B is constructed

where I guess the latter sounds better.

Comment: For me, rephrasing to "A is constructed in a way similar to B('s way of construction)" makes it clearer that the second statement is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is "the same as" or "similar to". As should not be used with similar.

See this ruling on [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/similar):

> similarity n ˈsimilarly
>
> adv
>
> Usage: As should not be used after similar: Wilson held a similar position to Jones (not a similar position as Jones); the system is similar to the one in France (not similar as the one in France)

Answer (score 6):

I'd use *in a similar way to*, but both are used.  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=similar%20way%20to,similar%20way%20as&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,similar%20way%20to;,c0;.t1;,similar%20way%20as;,c0) shows that *to* is the most used form.

Answer (score 2):

Here , `As` and `To` would mean to different things :

If you would use the word AS here , it would mean similie but you actually meant it to be an analogy(comparison)

So if you would want to show the similarity b/w the two:

> A is constructed as similarly as B.

But the more befitting phrase here would be:

> A is constructed similarly **to** B.

Why? because you are comparing both the diagrams , hence an analogy.

Answer (score 0):

Forget "similar as", grating though it may be: I have just seen "similar than" (twice so far, in the game Criminal Case, in which the English is often ... inventive). I guess this is an extension from "different than", so look out for "similar from": it's only a matter of time.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It would be better if you could include any reference/research (or a possible link) on your suggestion. I would advise you to take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here.